# mac login terminal error

Tags: macos, unix, authentication, terminal

http://meridianid.herobo.com/terminal_error.png

the first thing it does when i try to log in is display this error. on every window. can someone please help and find what 'login' is on line 400 or just know what the answer is? greatly appreciated.

cannot access terminal to debug myself :(

Comment: This belongs on superuser, I believe.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/232549/mac-terminal-error

Comment: i created that since someone *HEM* @jon told me to. that's MY question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of searching seems to suggest deleting /usr/bin/login remedies a similar error. However I would not blindly go deleting stuff. You could also try to use the repair permissions function of the Disk Utility, its solved many a strange problem before

Comment: though i have no way of doing this since i *have no terminal*

Comment: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa;jsessionid=992E46947386D3F07C583ECB7D00D881.node0?messageID=11656043&#11656043